# Get time overlaps and create an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to accomplish several things at once here. I'm starting with a params[:available_times] which are overall timespans (let's say 9am - 4pm, 6pm - 10pm) which get chopped up into time-slots (lengths are determined by service_length). I want to loop through the time-slots, and cross-reference them with my join table, sessions, and if that time-slot is taken, then return a 0, otherwise, return a 1, here is what I have so far:

```
 def available_times
    service_length = params[:service_length].to_i
    user = User.find(params[:id])

    timespans = []
    params[:available_times].each do |time|
        start_time = time.last[:availability_start].to_datetime
        end_time = time.last[:availability_end].to_datetime

        begin

            if user.sessions.where("start_time <= :session_end AND end_time >= :session_start",{session_start: start_time, session_end: start_time + service_length.minutes}).present?

                timespans << {time: start_time.to_datetime, available: 0}
            else
                timespans << {time: start_time.to_datetime, available: 1}
            end

        end while (start_time += service_length.minutes) < end_time

    end

    render json: timespans.to_json
end
```

So let's say I have a Session already in my user.sessions that lasts from 10am - 11am, my result should be:

```
[{time:9am, available:1}, {time:10am, available:0}, {time:11am, available:1}... and so on]
```

I created several sessions in my table that overlap and yet it still gives me all 1's.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the log while running, take note of the sql being run. Does it looks correct? Also, try running the relevant sql manually, see if it returns what you expect.

Comment: Yep, I checked out the logs, the data seems to be correct, and still when there is an overlap, it shows as none.